# Only first container repository of an Azure Container Registry can be used in App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service

I have an Azure Container Registry with two container repositories. If I create an app service I can only select the first registry.
Only way to select the other container image is to go on "private registry"

Comment: It is available now. It just took a very long time. But now it says: "Could not find the specified image name and tag combination" when trying to save

Comment: Are you positive you are selecting the correct combination?

Comment: it was nothing available to select. That is the issue.